# Corenlp parsing too slow for bad input

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

Corenlp parsing is too slow for bad input. It gives following kind of warnings, and takes lots of time for parsing.

For input:
"The Lincolns' fourth son, Thomas "Tad" Lincoln, was born on April 4, 1853, and died of heart failure at the age of 18 on July 16, 1871."

It is producing this error:

```
    Jul 24, 2015 4:03:42 PM edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder funkyFindLeafWithApproximateSpan
    WARNING: RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder: Failed to find head token:
    Tree is: (ROOT (S (NP (NP (NP (DT The) (NNS Lincolns) (POS ')) (JJ fourth) (NN son)) (, ,) (NP (NNP Thomas) () (NNP Tad) ('' '') (NNP Lincoln)) (, ,)) (VP (VP (VBD was) (VP (VBN born) (PP (IN on) (NP (NP (NNP April) (CD 4)) (, ,) (NP (CD 1853)) (, ,))))) (CC and) (VP (VBD died) (PP (IN of) (NP (NN heart) (NN failure))) (PP (IN at) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN age)) (PP (IN of) (NP (CD 18))))) (PP (IN on) (NP (NNP July) (CD 16))) (, ,) (NP (CD 1871)))) (. .)))
    token = |NP|0|, approx=0
    Jul 24, 2015 4:03:42 PM edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder funkyFindLeafWithApproximateSpan
    WARNING: RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder: Last resort: returning as head: 1871
    Jul 24, 2015 4:03:42 PM edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder findHead
    WARNING: Invalid index for head 34=34-0: originalSpan=[The Lincolns '], head=1871-35
    Jul 24, 2015 4:03:42 PM edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder findHead
    WARNING: Setting head string to entire mention
```

It took me 600.339 seconds to parse the cleaned text of this document https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln. 

 Is there any way to speed this thing up? Is there any option in corenlp to skip bad sentences automatically? or is there any way to set a time limit for parsing a sentence, after which parser will automatically skip the sentence?

Comment: If I recall correctly CoreNLP has issues with long sentences. Have you removed all markup junk from the document? What is the longest sentence?

Comment: Yes the sentences are clean. I am using SR parser. The problem is with dcoref function. It is taking too long. My sentences are pretty long, some are 60+ words (wikipedia sentences).

Comment: I think `dcoref` operates over the whole document. Take a look at the options for `dcoref` [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml), in particular `dcoref.maxdist`. The default setting is not to constrain the distance, so I imagine for long documents performance will decrease drastically.

Comment: As a test I ran the Abraham Lincoln page through my software. It took 959.76858 seconds with the default configuration and 115.11769 seconds with `dcoref.maxdist` set to `1`.

Comment: With maxdist = 1 it will only operate on single sentence level, which is not very much useful. Consider the text "Tom Cruise is a good actor. He played the lead role in MI series." Here 'He' will not map to 'Tom Cruise', thus we are loosing useful info.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right. I suggest that you play around with different values for `maxdist` to see what gives the best output / processing speed ratio. I haven't tested it, but I imagine as you increase `maxdist` you'll get diminishing returns (Edit: so a value of `maxdist` like `30` might give the same or better results than `-1`).